# PHPUnit: Correct Argument for Path in assertJsonStringEqualsJsonFile()

Tags: php, syntax, phpunit

Edit: PHPUnit version 4.5 stable.

The [official documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertJsonStringEqualsJsonFile) explains two arguments for the function:

```
assertJsonStringEqualsJsonFile($expectedFile, $actualJson)
```

$expectedFile is a path to a JSON file stored in the project. However, I am uncertain what the base directory is for the $expectedFile path. For example, if I have:

```
project-x/tests/MyClassTest.php
project-x/MyClass.php
project-x/tests/myJson.json
```

How do I point this function to myJson.json?

When I specify

```
asstertJsonStringEqualsJsonFile('tests/myJson', $myArg);
```

I keep getting errors like:

```
Failed asserting that file "tests/myJson.json" exists.
```

Or if I give the whole path:

```
asstertJsonStringEqualsJsonFile('/home/user-x/myproject/way/deep/tests/myJson', $myArg);
```

I get:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Argument #1 (No Value) of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertJson() must be a string
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant. When you call `tests/MyClass.php` in test case use:

```
asstertJsonStringEqualsJsonFile(__DIR__ . '/myJson.json', $myArg);
```